# signal handling in linux and interrupted function calls?

Tags: c++, c, process, signals, shared-memory

I need to solve a problem which is described as

There are two processes p1, p2 and two variables x , y process p1 and p2 should update value of x and y as p1 will update y = x + 1 and  p2 will update x = y + 1 with consistency .i.e. When p1 is reading x at the same time p2 can't write updated value of x  and when p1 is writing y at the same time p2 can't read the value of y .

By looking at problem we can observed that there is deadlock. `(read-x by p1)-->(read-y by p1) -->(update-y by p1)-->(read-y by p2)-->(read-x by p2) --> (update-x by p2 )`

To resolve deadlock i wrote a program which uses signal and shared memory.
In main function signal handler is registered using `SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2` signal number which is handled by signal handler func1()  and func2().Signal is generated too synchronize the value of x and y . Whenever process p1 complete it's work then it generates a signal for process p2  which is transferred using `Kill(pid,signo) and vice versa` they do their work in infinite loop and sleep for some times.

It prints correct(consistent) output but there is a problem with this implementation as 
**Initially it takes few seconds to print output after that it prints large no of sequences (bunch of lines) at a time .**

What modification should be done in this code so that it prints output after almost constant amount of time ?

One may suggest use equal amount of sleep time but it didn't work.

```
    void func1(int signo){
        *shm2 = *shm1 +1;
        cout<<"Value of Y is\t"<<*shm2<<"\n";
        signal(signo,func1);
    }

    void func2(int signo){
        *shm1  = *shm2 + 1;
        cout<<"Value of X is\t"<<*shm1<<"\n";
        signal(signo,func2);
    }

    int main(){

    int pid=0,ppid=0;
    int shmid1,shmid2;
    signal(SIGUSR1,func1);
    signal(SIGUSR2,func2);

    shmid1 = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE , sizeof(int) , 0666|IPC_CREAT);
    shmid2 = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE , sizeof(int) , 0666|IPC_CREAT);

    if(shmid1 < 0 || shmid2 < 0 ){
        cout<<"Something goes wrong during creation\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    // Attach shared memory to an address 
    shm1  = (int *) shmat(shmid1 , (void*)0 , 0);
    shm2  = (int *) shmat(shmid2 , (void*)0 , 0);
    if( *shm1 == -1 || *shm2 == -1){
        cout<<"Memory can't be attached\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    pid   = fork();
    if(pid < 0 ){
        cout<<"fork() error\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    ppid  =getppid();
    if(pid > 0){
        while(1){
        sleep(500);
        kill(pid,SIGUSR1);
        }
    }
    else{
        while(1){
        sleep(5);
        kill(ppid,SIGUSR2);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Side Note: Are you calling `fork` twice intentionally? The result is that you are creating 4 processes instead of 2.

Comment: @DiegoNietoCid   There was an error in copy paste . I am not calling fork() . Do you have any idea why o/p comes like that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not deadlock. A deadlock is a situation where P1 waits P2 to finish and P2 waits P1 to finish...

Your problem is a eventually a matter of concurrent access and the solution is to use locks. A lock lets a program/thread to accomplish some task atomically. The strategy is to use a lock `L` shared by the two process/threads in such a way: `GET(L); do some task; RELEASE(L);`

What is wrong in your code is that signal delivery interrupts your `sleep` calls. And when such a call is interrupted it does not restart at the end of the handling. The manuel says:

> If the sleep() function returns due to     the delivery of a signal,
>   the value returned will be the unslept amount     (the requested time
>   minus the time actually slept) in seconds.

So you can modify your loops like this:

```
   if (pid > 0) {
        while(1) {
          int v = 500;
          while ((v=sleep(v))!=0); // restart while delay not passed
          kill(pid,SIGUSR1);
        }
    }
    else {
        while(1) {
          int v=5;
          while ((v=sleep(v))!=0); // restart while delay not passed
          kill(ppid,SIGUSR2);
        }
    }
```

I can also suggest not to use the old `signal` interface but `sigaction` which is more safe and reliable (you will never have to reset the `signal` handling in the signal handler for example).